# How do you add a DLL reference to a .NET WebAPI project?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and .NET 4.5 and the new WebAPI project type. However, I am unable to add a reference to my class library project to the WebAPI project. Does this need to be a "portable class library" project or can it be a regular one? There's no error, it just doesn't get added!

Comment: what is the class library? is it a native assembly?

Comment: @DanielA.White It is a C# assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alrighty so in Visual Studio 2012 there's a check box next to each reference you want to add, in the add references menu.

It's very non-intuitive. We've gone away from selecting things by highlighting and have moved to check boxes.

Comment: This, unfortunately, is true sometimes... >.<

Comment: @dodexahedron I've edited this to make it actually an answer! I've found the culprit.

Comment: Thanks! Sheesh, I can't believe that UI cue completely escaped me.